# Why do I have to delete my app every time before running it in the simulator?

Tags: xcode

[image: This app could not be installed at this time]

When I press the play button in XCode (Version 9.4.1 (9F2000)) on High Sierra, it shows this popup:

**This app could not be installed at this time.**

If I delete the app from the simulated phone and then press the play button again, it installs and runs fine.

Why do I have to delete the app every time from the simulated phone?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some pods in your app, try to delete and install them again. I had a similar problem, and the pods were the reason of this error.